# If synchronized creates a happen-before relationship and prevents reordering why is volatile needed for DCL

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to understand the need for `volatile` in double-checked locking (I'm aware there are better ways than DCL though) I've read a few SO questions similar to mine, but none seem to explain what I'm looking for. I've even found some upvoted answers on SO that have said volatile is not needed (even when the object is mutable) however, everything I've read says otherwise.

What I want to know is why volatile is necessary in DCL if synchronized creates a [happens-before relationship](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) and [prevents reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274038/does-synchronized-keyword-prevent-reordering-in-java)?

Here is my understanding of how DCL works and an [example](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/05/double-checked-locking.html):

```
// Does not work
class Foo {
  private Helper helper = null; // 1
  public Helper getHelper() { // 2
    if (helper == null) { // 3
      synchronized(this) { // 4
        if (helper == null) { // 5
          helper = new Helper(); // 6
        } // 7
      } // 8
    } // 9
  return helper; // 10
}
```

This does not work because the Helper object is not `immutable` or `volatile` and we know that
`volatile` causes every write to be flushed to memory and for every read to come from memory. This is important so that no thread sees a stale object.

So in the example I listed, it's possible for `Thread A` to begin initializing a new `Helper` object at *Line 6*. Then `Thread B` comes along and see a half initialized object at *line 3*. `Thread B` then jumps to *line 10* and returns a half initialized `Helper` object.

Adding `volatile` fixes this with a `happens before` relationship and no reordering can be done by the JIT compiler. So the `Helper` object cannot be written to the helper reference until it is fully constructed (?, at least this is what I think it is telling me...).

However, after reading [JSR-133 documentation](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html), I became a bit confused. It states

> Synchronization ensures that memory writes by a thread before or
>   during a synchronized block are made visible in a predictable manner
>   to other threads which synchronize on the same monitor. After we exit
>   a synchronized block, we release the monitor, which has the effect of
>   flushing the cache to main memory, so that writes made by this thread
>   can be visible to other threads. Before we can enter a synchronized
>   block, we acquire the monitor, which has the effect of invalidating
>   the local processor cache so that variables will be reloaded from main
>   memory. We will then be able to see all of the writes made visible by
>   the previous release.

So `synchronized` in Java creates a memory barrier and a happens before relationship.

So the actions are being flushed to memory, so it makes me question why `volatile` is needed on the variable.

The documentation also states

> This means that any memory operations which were visible to a thread
>   before exiting a synchronized block are visible to any thread after it
>   enters a synchronized block protected by the same monitor, since all
>   the memory operations happen before the release, and the release
>   happens before the acquire.

My guess as to why we need the `volatile` keyword and why `synchronize` is not enough, is because the memory operations are not visible to other threads until `Thread A` exits the synchronized block and `Thread B` enters the same block on the same lock.

It's possible that `Thread A` is initializing the object at *line 6* and `Thread B` comes along at *Line 3* before there is a flush by `Thread A` at *Line 8.*

However, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23274240/2951367) seems to contradict that as the synchronized block prevents reordering "from inside a synchronized block, to outside it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If helper is not null, what ensures that the code will see all the effects of the construction of the helper? Without `volatile`, nothing would do so.

Consider:

```
  synchronized(this) { // 4
    if (helper == null) { // 5
      helper = new Helper(); // 6
    } // 7
```

Suppose internally this is implemented as first setting `helper` to a non-null value and then calling the constructor to create a valid `Helper` object. No rule prevents this.

Another thread may see `helper` as non-null but the constructor hasn't even run yet, much less made its effects visible to another thread.

It is vital not to permit any other thread to see `helper` set to a non-null value until we can guarantee that all consequences of the constructor are visible to that thread.

By the way, getting code like this correct is extremely difficult. Worse, it can appear to work fine 100% of the time and then suddenly break on a different JVM, CPU, library, platform, or whatever. It is generally advised that writing this kind of code be avoided unless proven to be needed to meet performance requirements. This kind of code is hard to write, hard to understand, hard to maintain, and hard to get right.

Comment: The documentation I linked states: "After we exit a synchronized block, we release the monitor, which has the effect of flushing the cache to main memory, so that writes made by this thread can be visible to other threads." I might be misinterpreting this quote, but wouldn't other threads be able to see the object? And if synchronized prevents reordering from inside a synchronized block, to outside it, I thought that another thread would not see a non-null but non-constructed object.

Comment: All the code above is inside the synchronized block. So the fact that other code outside the synchronized block won't be interleaved with it doesn't help us. Both modifications occur inside the synchronized block, so they can occur in either order. As for when the flush occurs, that doesn't matter. Both modifications occur inside the synchronized block. So what happens when or as we leave it doesn't matter. We can blow up while the thread is still inside the synchronized block.

Comment: Perhaps you have the misunderstanding that everything inside the `synchronized` block occurs atomically and nothing inside it can possibly be visible until we leave the block at which point it all becomes visible. But if you think about it, that's impossible. (Think about, for example, one `synchronized` function that calls another `synchronized` function.)

Comment: I think I misinterpreted what "synchronized prevents reordering from inside a synchronized block, to outside it" actually meant. However, it does sound like my initial assumption was right. Once we leave the synchronized block, the object will be visible to all other threads, however, things can go bad if the constructing thread is still constructing the object.

Comment: The main failure case is when we're still constructing the object and another thread sees non-null. We need to make sure no thread can possibly see non-null unless it is guaranteed to see all consequences of the construction of the object.

Comment: @eric: 1) Memory flushes are side effects, they have no guarantees on their own, in order to have guarantees, you must use a memory order such as happens-before, synchronization order, program order, etc 2) Volatile isn't there to protect against instruction reordering, it's there to produce the aforementioned order such that initialization causes the appropriate memory effects for other threads to see the correctly initialized values 3) Setting an object reference is atomic, you can't initialize an object while another thread observes it unless you have unsafely published the this reference

Answer (score 1):

@David Schwartz's answer is pretty good but there is one thing that I'm not sure is stated well.

> My guess as to why we need the volatile keyword and why synchronize is not enough, is because the memory operations are not visible to other threads until Thread A exits the synchronized block and Thread B enters the same block on the same lock.

Actually not the same lock but any lock because locks come with memory barriers.  `volatile` is not about locking but it is around crossing memory barriers while  `synchronized` blocks are both locks and memory barriers.  You need the `volatile` because even though Thread A has properly initialized the `Helper` instance and published it to `helper` field, Thread B needs to *also* cross a memory barrier to ensure that it sees all of the updates to `Helper`.

> So in the example I listed, it's possible for Thread A to begin initializing a new Helper object at Line 6. Then Thread B comes along and see a half initialized object at line 3. Thread B then jumps to line 10 and returns a half initialized Helper object.

Right.  It is possible that Thread A might initialize the `Helper` and publish it *before* it hits the end of the `synchronized` block.  There is nothing stopping it from happening.  And because the JVM is allowed to reorder the instructions from the `Helper` constructor until later, it could be published to `helper` field but not be fulling initialized.  And even if Thread A does reach the end of the `synchronized` block and `Helper` then gets fully initialized, there is still nothing that ensures that Thread B sees all of the updated memory.

> However, this SO answer seems to contradict that as the synchronized block prevents reordering "from inside a synchronized block, to outside it"

No, that answer is not contradictory.  You are confusing what happens with just Thread A and what happens to other threads.  In terms of Thread A (and central memory), exiting the `synchronized` block makes sure that `Helper`'s constructor has fully finished and published to the `helper` field.  But this means nothing until Thread B (or other threads) *also* cross a memory barrier.  Then they too will invalidate the local memory cache and see all of the updates.

That's why the `volatile` is necessary.

Comment: no. for the proper guarantees to happen it *has* to be the same lock, it's even [under the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) . You are probably right in practice about different locks, but boooy that is thin and dangerous

Comment: There is the language spec and there is the memory synchronization specs.  The language spec mentions the same lock but the memory specs disagree.  Might be thin but the realities are that to provide per-lock memory semantics would be prohibitive.  But I agree there is no guarantee @Eugene.